# Workbook_BeforeClose() works in the first part, but does not close the Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Workbooks: Workbook A and Workbook B.
I am trying to open Workbook B once the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` function of Workbook A is called (by closing the Workbook).
This step is working (so Workbook B is opened). But after opening Workbook B, Workbook A remains open and has to be closed manually again (this time the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` function is not called again).

I encountered two problems:

1. Workbook A is not closed after the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` function is called.
2. The opened Workbook B is opened in a strange format (Excel menu bar and the title bar (to minimize and close the window) are missing.

This never happened before when I used the `Workbooks.Open()` function with other workbooks.

Also the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` function is working perfectly, while only the *logEntry* Sub is called (no `Workbooks.Open()`).

Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim wbA As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Workbook A (the one to close) is the ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook

    'Sub to add some data to a Log.txt (works fine at this point).
    Call logEntry

    'Open Workbook B only if Workbook A is ReadOnly 
    '(I replaced the full path with <>, but the original path is correct. Workbook B opens)
    If wbA.ReadOnly = True Then
         Workbooks.Open Filename:= <path as String>, ReadOnly:=True
    End If      

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have tried to add `wb.Close()` after Workbook B is opened, but this results in an error, because the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` function is called again by this.

Comment: Please enable both `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` to see what exactly is happening and if there is any alert while closing the workbook ?

Comment: I have enabled both now. The only alert showing up is, when opening Workbook B, Excel asks to enable Makros. After allowing it, Workbook B is building up (in the strange format mentioned) and Workbook A remains open until closed manually. There are no other observable alerts.

Comment: One of the reason for the Workbook B to open is strange format could be due to `ReadOnly:=True` argument. I'm trying to replicate the issue but I'm using Mac, so have a little hard time with it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try maybe with `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the very beginning of your code, or one line before opening your new workbook?

Comment: I deleted the ReadOnly:=True and also tried to EnableEvents (on the beginning and one line before). I tested both individually and together, but the problem still remains the same at this point. Also no additional alerts or messages are showing up.

Comment: I just tried the above code and it worked as expected. You may additionally try adding  Cancel = False after Workbook.open.... to ensure the close event execute properly.

Comment: I have also tested to assign Cancel = False again after opening Workbook B. But sadly the song remains the same. Just if I delete the line to open Workbook B, Workbook A is closing properly. May there be some problem that Workbook B has Makros which are called once the file is opened? On the other hand, Workbook B can also be opened from a UserForm I have in a different Workbook (lets name it C... :D) and by opening it that way, everything is working fine.

Comment: Not sure why it behaves like that, but maybe try forcing Excel to close the wbA, so... add a Public variable (at the top of `ThisWorkbook` object, `Public bClose as Boolean`) and then call it at the end of your `BeforeClose` event, just before `End Sub`: `If bClose then Exit Sub`

Comment: I did as you suggested. I have also checked the value of `bClose` (it is "False"). Also the Sub (`Workbook_BeforeClose()`) seems to work after Workbook B is opened. But still, Workbook A remains open and Workbook B has its funny format.

Comment: Hmmm I would expect `bClose` to be `True`... can you force it in your code? As in `bClose = True` before you run `If bClose then Exit Sub` (I promise this is the last try :p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the method is that your code is opening the `Workbook B` in the same excel application which you are then trying to quit. Due to which the `Workbook A` never closes on exit function.

Please use the below code to open `Workbook B` in a new excel application.

```vb
If wbA.ReadOnly = True Then
    Set app = New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = True
    app.Workbooks.Open Filename:="<Workbook B path>", ReadOnly:=True
End If
```